# why do i get nzec error on my code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

why do i get nzec error on my code on codechef????? Please help
question link is    http://www.codechef.com/problems/DCE05
and my solution is

```
maxn = 10**9

i = 0

lis = [1]

while(maxn !=0):

    lis.append(2*lis[i])

    i = i+1

    maxn = maxn/2

t = int(input())

for y in range(t):

    n = int(input())

    if n == 0:

        print n

        continue

    for j in range(len(lis)):

        if n > lis[j]:

            continue

        else:

            if lis[j]== n:

                print lis[j]

            else:

                print lis[j-1]

            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very easy to answer, but are you sure you shouldn't first read all the input, and then print the output ? From what I understand, with input 2 5 10, your code will first read 2 (the number of test cases, then 5 (the number of people) print the first result, and only then read the next input 10. I am not sure if this can help but it is easy to try.

Comment: this doesn't help, since they accept answers in that format also.
Any other suggestion is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I've done programming contests before, you are supposed to read all the input before producing any output, instead of interleaving both. Running your code with the test case [2,5,12] provided on the page gives

```
2
5
4
12
8
```

while what it should show

```
2
5
12
4
8
```

Comment: i use the same format to give output for many other question asked and it always get accepted. I think that the format you suggested doesn't work. Any other help would be helpful. Thanks